# Powershell script to convert PDF to TIFF with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, powershell, ghostscript

I have been asked to write a script that automatically converts PDF files to TIFF files so they can be processed furter. With a lot of help from Google and this site. (I never studied any programming language) I created the code below. 
Even though it's working now, it is not quite what I was hoping for since it creates 13 files every time it runs where it should create only 1.

Could someone be kind enough to take a look at the script and tell me where I went wrong?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: 
In this (test) case there's only one PDF in the folder and it's named test.pdf, however the idea is that the script looks through all the PDF in the given folder since it's unsure how many PDF's are in the folder at any given time. Let it run as a service in the background(?)

I'll edit the post with the error code/description once I find out how to get them, I can't keep up with the command line.

```
#Path to your Ghostscript EXE
$tool = 'C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.10\\bin\\gswin64c.exe'

#Directory containing the PDF files that will be converted
$inputDir = 'C:\\test\\'

#Output path where converted PDF files will be stored
$outputDirPDF = 'C:\\test\\oud\\'

#Output path where the TIF files will be saved
$outputDir = 'C:\\test\\TIFF'

$pdfs = get-childitem $inputDir -recurse | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{

    $tif = $outputDir + $pdf.BaseName + ".tif"
    if(test-path $tif)
    {
        "tif file already exists " + $tif
    }
    else        
    {   
        'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
        $param = "-sOutputFile=$tif"
        & $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
    }
    Move-Item $pdf $outputDirPDF
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working now, apparently I was missing an "exit" at the end of the code. It might not be the most beautiful piece of code, but it seems to do the job so I'm happy with it. 
Below the piece of code that actually works;

```
#Path to your Ghostscript EXE
$tool = 'C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.10\\bin\\gswin64c.exe'

#Directory containing the PDF files that will be converted
$inputDir = 'C:\\test\\'

#Output path where converted PDF files will be stored
$outputDirPDF = 'C:\\test\\oud\\'

#Output path where the TIF files will be saved
$outputDir = 'C:\\test\\TIFF\\'

$pdfs = get-childitem $inputDir -recurse | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{
    $tif = $outputDir + $pdf.BaseName + ".tif"
    if(test-path $tif)
    {
        "tif file already exists " + $tif
    }
    else        
    {   
        'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
        $param = "-sOutputFile=$tif"
        & $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
    }
    Move-Item $pdf $outputDirPDF
}
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be creating one TIFF file for each PDF file in the source directory. How many PDF files are in the directory (and any sub-directories) ? How many pages in the input PDF file ?

I note that you move the original PDF from 'InputDir' to 'OutputDirPDF' when completed, but 'OutputDirPDF' is a child of 'InputDir', so if you recurse child directories when looking for input files you may find files you have already processed. NB I know nothing about Powershell so this may be just fine.

I'd suggest making 'InputDir' and 'OutputDirPDF' at the same level, eg "c:\temp\input" and "c:\temp\outputPDF".

That's about all I can say on the information here, you could state what the input PDF filename(s) and output Filename(s) are, and what the processing messages say.

Comment: In this testcase there was only one PDF, but the idea is that it should loop through multiple PDF's as well since it's unsure how many PDF's will be in the folder.

Comment: Well I can't see any reason you end up with multiple files in the output unless either the script is picking up the file PDF file after you move it, or the input file has multiple pages. A list of the output filenames and maybe a link to the iput PDF might help, maybe.....

Comment: If I change the inputdir to C:\\test\\test.pdf, it runs exactly how it's supposed to. However (obviously) it won't loop through all PDF's since the filename is coded in there rather then letting the code figure it out. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I don't know anything about Powershell, but this is clearly not a Ghostscript problem. I would say that your problem is most likely what I mentioned in my answer, when you move the input PDF then you are moving it to a child directory, so get-childitem -recurse will find the PDF file in its new location. As I said, to sure that either don't use -recurse, or move the processed file to a directory that isn't a child of the one passed to get-childitem.

Comment: Actually now I see it the final line 'Move-Item $pdfs $OutputDirPDF' is inside the foreach loop so it will happen on every pass round the loop. I very much doubt you want that to happen. Seems that should either be outside the loop (so you move them after processing all of them) or that should read 'Move-Item $pdf $outputDirPDF' so that you move the file just processed, rather than the array containing all the PDF files discovered.

Comment: That´s a valid, point. Now that I think of it, that doesn´t makes much sense, so I changed the line into Move-Item $pdf $outputDirPDF and it does move multiple files now, however it keeps making 13 TIF´s even if there are only 2 PDF´s in the folder and I still can´t figure out why. I also updated the code in the start post

Comment: How are the TIFF files named ? What processing messages do you get ? I did ask this earlier but you haven't given that information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed your question. The files are named as followed, the original name plus "- copy(xx)" where the X's stand for a number. For example "test - copy(1)". Regarding the messages, it seems to run without warnings now, would you like me to copy the entire text it shows while it runs?

Comment: Well that's pretty odd. Ghostscript can't be doing that, which means its your script/Windows. What do the various processing messages say ? Somewhere in there something ought to be telling you what the filename its processing is. I presume you are deleting the existing tiff files before doing the test ? Oh, and deleting the files in OutputDirPDF as well ? That one looks like a possibility to me, Move-Item might well rename the files on copy if they exist.

Comment: it appears that adding an "exit" at the end of the code fixed the problem, I still don't really understand why, but I'm still happy with it. I added the piece of code that's working for me just in case someone else happens to have this problem too.